# Polar form of complex numbers3

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $z$ be the complex number $z=-2+i$ and let the angle $\phi$ be such that tan$\phi=1/2$ and $-\pi/2<\phi<-\pi/2$.

Calculate the modulus $|z|$ and describe the principal argument arg$(z)$ using $\phi$. And express $z$ in polar form.

Anyone knows how to go about this problem? I mean the modulus is $\sqrt{5}$ but honestly I don't understand anything of the principal argument thing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You know the form $ z=r*e^{\theta i} $?

Comment: You need to solve for $\theta $ in $ tan (\theta)=1/2$ given the interval.

Comment: and how do I do that? just inverse tan 1/2?

Comment: Yes, but you must stay in the interval.

Comment: ahh ok and how do I do that? just +pi so my solution is: 5^(1/2)*(cos(tan^-1(1/2)+pi) + isin(tan^-1(1/2)+pi))?

Comment: Not sure where $\pi $ is coming from, but if you realize that the inverse tan function by definition must stay in $[-{\pi}/2,{\pi}/2] $, and your calculator obeys that you should realize that there is no correction necessary.  Also plot $2+i$ in the complex plane. That should help too. Then go $z=e^{\theta i} $

Comment: Actually you should, I missed minus. $\pi -\tan^{-1} (1/2) $

Comment: well that depends, if I should solve tan(θ)=1/2 like you wrote in ur first comment, (but I guess that stay in the interval anyway?) or if I should find tan^-1 (1/-2) ??

Comment: Right sorry, I don't know why that interval is there. Do $\tan^{-1} (-1/2) $.you will get the angle the problem ask for, but that is not technically the correct angle in polar form. It's a strange problem. That angle gives you the correct angle when you evaluate it, but technically the angle I told you just before is correct in polar form.

Comment: Actually I just got it. Do $ $ $tan^{-1}(-1/2)$. Keep that angle make your modulus negative

Comment: Yeah, but they might want $ z=-\sqrt (5)e^{tan^{-1}(-1/2) i} $ which is the same thing in polar form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **polar form** of a complex number is the expression
$$z = r(\cos \theta  + i\sin \theta )$$

Here $r$ is the modulus and $\theta$ is the argument. We call it the principal argument if it is between $- \pi$ and $\pi$.

If you plot $z$ in the complex plane, $r$ is the distance from the origin to $z$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the line segment from the origin to $z$ and the positive $x$ axis.

To solve your problem, draw the complex plan, plot your particular $z$, draw the line segment from the origin to $z$, draw the line segment from $z$ to the $x$-axis, and contemplate the figure. You should be able to figure it out.